# Find the most vowel words in the sentence (which can be several maximal words that are equivalent to each other)

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, static

**Count vowel in the word for method**

```
public class Methods6 {
 public static int countVowel(String words) {
        int count = 0;
        char[] vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
            char ch = words.charAt(i);
            for (char cc : vowel) {
                if (ch == cc) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

**Find max vowel in sentence **

```
public static String maxVowelWords() {
      String sentence = getSentence().toLowerCase();
      String words[] = sentence.split(" ");
      int maxvowel = CountVowel(words[0]), count;
      String maxWord = words[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
          count = CountVowel(words[i]);
          if (count > maxvowel) {
              maxvowel = count;
              maxWord = words[i] + " ";
          }
      }
      return maxWord;

  }}// 2 methods are located  in the same Method Class
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(Methods6.MaxVowelWords());}}
```

*When writing this method, it gives only the first word with the most vowel letters (eg. --------- hello my friend! ----------- just hello, hello and friend -------no!
How can I change the method of this?*
Thanks for helps!

Comment: It the `for` loop, i must start with `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpret this question is that:

- Find the word in the supplied String which contains the most vowels
  in it.
- If one or more words within that very same String contain equal
  maximum number of vowels then concatenate the words together
  delimited by a whitespace (or whatever).

So, if the String supplied was: `"hello my friend"` then both words, `hello` and `friend`, would be returned from the **maxVowelWords()** method in the form of (let's say):

```
hello, friend
```

Since both `hello` and `friend` contain 2 vowels which so happens to be the the max number of vowels in any given word then both words are returned.

If the supplied string however was: `"hello my friend - I live on the Mississippi river."` then only **Mississippi** is returned from the method since it is the **only** word within that String that contains a maximun number of 4 vowels. All other words containing vowels within the string contain a lesser vowel count.

If this is indeed the situation then your method should look something like this:

```
public static String maxVowelWords() {
    String sentence = getSentence();
    String words[] = sentence.split(" ");
    int maxvowel = 0; 
    String maxWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int count = countVowels(words[i]);
        if (count == maxvowel) {
            maxvowel = count;
            // Ternary Operator is used here to applt the delimiter (", ") if needed,
            maxWord += (maxWord.equals("") ? words[i] : ", " + words[i]) + " (" + count + " vowels)";
        }
        else if(count > maxvowel) {
            maxvowel = count;
            maxWord = words[i] + " (" + count + " vowels)";;
        }
    }
    return maxWord;
}
```

Yes, you start your loop from 0 and **maxWord** String variable should be initialized to hold an empty string (""). Let the **for** loop do its work. And No, **count** is not a waste, it's actually a requirement in order to to acquire the maximum vowel count for **maxvowel** as each string word is placed through the process.

You utilize a method named **getSentence()** to acquire the String to process and right away you distort that Original String by setting it to all lower case. You really shouldn't do that since the words you return from your **maxVowelWords()** method will not be the originally supplied words should they happen to have upper case vowels. A small modification to the **countVowel()** method can take care of that business, for example:

```
if (Character.toLowerCase(ch) == cc) {
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few bugs in your code. Try this :

```
public static String maxVowelWords() {
    String sentence = getSentence().toLowerCase();
    String words[] = sentence.split(" ");
    int maxvowel = 0, count;
    String maxWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        count = countVowel(words[i]);
        if (count > maxvowel) {
            maxvowel = count;
            maxWord = "";
        }
        if(count == maxvowel){
            maxWord = maxWord  + words[i]+ " ";
        }
    }
    return maxWord.trim();

}
```

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if this helps you.

Comment: hi, hello friend ---- if i give this sentence i get result-->
 friend

Comment: It would most likely be good if you explained what you found as bugs. Where is **count** declared?

Comment: thank you, I tried this method before sharing this question, but when max. vowel words are neighbor is result does not as expected!

Comment: @UlviIbrahimli Edited my solution. Coverted else-if to if. It should work now.